# How save a csv with pandas named with values of an array?

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu

if I have an array of x values, for doing something, how can is it possible to save results in a .csv file that every time is named by a value of x using pandas: for example tempCSV_(x).csv?

I show the code example:

```
list_of_x=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]

for x in list_of_x:

       <do something>

  tempCSV.to_csv(tempCSV+ '.csv')
```

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just name the file x (but wrap the float in `str()`):

```
list_of_x=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]

for x in list_of_x:

       <do something>

  tempCSV.to_csv(str(x) + '.csv')
```

Comment: thank you so muck @RJ Ariaansen very useful

Comment: and If I would have the name tempCSV_str(x)_anotherfixedword.csv? Sorry

Comment: That would be `tempCSV.to_csv('tempCSV_' + str(x) + '_anotherfixedword.csv')` or you could use f-string formatting in python 3.6+: `tempCSV.to_csv(f'tempCSV_{x}_anotherfixedword.csv')`